# Get the actual socket from SocketException

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, socketexception

How do I get the current socket from a SocketException?

I have a list of all available sockets and if the socket is no longer available I would like to remove it from the list.

```
try
{
    /* Socket stuff */
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == (int)SocketError.ConnectionAborted)
    {
        // Remove socket from list
        ConnectionAborted( currentSocket );
    }
}
```

I have checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.aspx), but couldn't find anything.

So the method `ConnectionAborted` should remove the socket where the problem occurs from the list so it no longer check for new data.

Comment: Isn't `currentSocket` declared above `try` ?

Comment: Refactor the /* socket stuff */ so it's catching an exception where currentSocket is in scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A SocketException is thrown by the Socket and Dns classes when an error occurs with the network.*

This means that one of the methods of `Socket` objects throws `SocketException`, therefore you already know its source and the code shpould be something like this:

```
Socket currentSocket;

try
{
    /* Socket stuff with currentSocket */
}
catch (SocketException se)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == (int)SocketError.ConnectionAborted)
    {
                    //Remove socket from list
        ConnectionAborted( currentSocket ); // At his point currentSocket is in scope.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be possible to get it directly from SocketException but this works as well.